# taco support for cordova 6.4.0 and IOS 4.3.0 cocoapods doesn't seem to work

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I upgraded my app to cordova 6.4.0 and ios 4.3.0.  I also updated the plugin phonegap-plugin-push to 1.9.0 which now uses cocoapods in plugin.xml

```
<framework src="GoogleCloudMessaging" type="podspec" spec="~> 1.2.0"/>
<framework src="GGLInstanceID" type="podspec" spec="~> 1.2.1"/>
```

After installing cocoapods on the mac with

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

I now get a compilation error in XCode saying GoogleCloudMessaging.h is not found.

So, is TACO not ready yet for ios 4.3.0, or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Just noticed this remotebuild issue : https://github.com/Microsoft/remotebuild/issues/10, so this might be because of this.  I will update when this bug is fixed.